# Authorization between Delphi app and web server

Tags: authorization

I have Lazarus(quite a lot like Delphi) application which downloads few files from https://example.com/UpdateFolder. And i was wondering if anything can be done in order for APP to know that it is downloading files from right website? Because if I am right there is a way for hacker to trick APP into going to different website and downloading wrong files and I think it is done somehow by editing system32/driver/etc/hosts file.  I would appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on your application that downloads the files. If it's able to handle SSL you have nothing to worry about AFAIK, since you need a trusted certificate before it'll make the connection, which will be hard to fake with a Windows host file edit.

Alternatively, and this is why we have domain names in the first place - so a last resort, you could hard-code the IP address of the server that contains the updates and do a trace to make sure the IP of the website your application is connecting to, is the same one you have on file.

However, this makes it very difficult if that IP changes, since you then need to roll out a new update of your entire application (or dll's responsible) just for that, and makes the process that much harder to maintain...